# C# coalesce operator doesn't replace a null method return value?

Tags: c#, coalesce, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

I have this code:

```
MyClass _localMyClass = MyClassDAO.GetMyClassByID(123) ?? new MyClass();
```

This is the method:

```
    public static MyClass GetMyClassByID(int id)
    {
        var query = from m in ctx.MyClass
                    where m.MyClassID == id
                    select m;

        return query.FirstOrDefault<MyClass>();
    }
```

So the `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't find a hit in the entity framework context, which is the "ctx" object.  So the 'default' value to be returned is `null`, since the target of the query is a class.

The result of the first bit of code, using the `??`, results in `_localMyClass` being what?  I would say it would be the `new MyClass()`.  Instead, `_localMyClass` ends up being null.  I tried grouping the logic with various sets of parentheses, but still no luck.

Odder still; when I set a debug break point, and copy/paste the `MyClassDAO.GetMyClassByID(123) ?? new MyClass()` into the watch screen of Visual Studio, the result is the `new MyClass()` instead of `null`.

Can anybody explain why it would be working in this manner?  Why it doesn't recognize the method return value as `null` and then instead use the `new` part?

Comment: Alternatively, you can avoid the use of `operator??` by modifying your return statement to be `return query.DefaultIfEmpty(new MyClass()).First();`

Comment: Try breaking it up into two lines (`MyClass _localMyClass = MyClassDAO.GetMyClassByID(123); _localMyClass = _localMyClass ?? new MyClass();`) and stepping through it.

Comment: Can you show the entire class?  I'd like to see where the top line is in relation to the rest of it.

Comment: Wow... I'm a bit cranky now... I closed and reopened Visual Studio 2010... and it works fine now.  Nice.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  And I appreciate all the suggestions VERY MUCH!  I can't 'answer my own question' for 8 hours.

Comment: @Austin did you take a look at my answer?  That makes me further suspect it was a conditional breakpoint or watch value that was actually setting it to null rather than anything wrong with the code.

Comment: @Davy8 - No, no conditions, and I keep my breakpoints clean (empty).  I have seen things like this before.  Should have remembered to try that first when I know the syntax should have worked.

Comment: @Steve Guidi - I like that suggestion, but I'm working on a large project and can't risk changing the return value of a method unless I want to be responsible for re-factoring any code that calls it.  It would be a good option for a new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and reopening Visual Studio, the code worked fine.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 w/ service pack 1.

I have had this happen in the past, and should have remembered to try it first.  I have noticed that VS seems to behave strangely sometimes, especially when running the web application in debug, specifically when running the web app locally (from my local IIS) and attaching to w3wp.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess because I made this mistake before and it baffled me for the longest time.

Do you have a conditional breakpoint and in that conditional breakpoint do you have the condition as `_localMyClass = null`?

One time I did something like that when I meant to write `==` in the conditional breakpoint and it resulted in the debugger setting the value to null.  Similarly do you have any watch values that could be setting it to null?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since the self-answer has already been accepted, a pro-forma answer in case anyone needs another possible case in the future:

```
 FirstOrDefault()
```

will in fact return the **default value** which can be **`null`** for object references, but cannot be that for **value-types**. If **`MyClass`** is a valuetype (think: `struct`) you'd be better of

- checking for default(T) in a generic method
- using a specific value using DefaultIfEmpty() extension
- using the `MyClass?` nullable type (short for Nullable)

$0.02

Comment: Excellent point on the value-type.  Always be sure you know what it is that you are running a query against and what the return value should be.  In my example, if somebody modified the query to return a field in MyClass, instead of the entire MyClass, then odds are that field would be a value-type (int, bool, etc.), which would then indeed fail the ?? check since value types can't be null.  The firstOrDefault() would instead return a 0 for int fields, false for bools, etc.  If you are not sure what FirstOrDefault() will return, ALWAYS double check!